# Why is my mouse bigger when I'm in Nautilus? How can I fix it? (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: 22.04, mouse

It seems to only occur in certain apps. The cursor appears larger in some windows/apps, yet in others, such as Firefox (snap), it maintains its expected size.

Why is this happening, and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same user here. Seems like an issue with resolution taken by these apps (not sure in which way). I changed my resolution to 720p and then again to 1080p, and mouse seems fixed in these apps I mentioned.